# Put more than two values in d3 div

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So, I have a map that I want to display a div with a wellheads name, but the variable 'value' is overwriting and only the last value is getting.

The following is not working:

```js
var value = [];

wellheads.forEach(function(d) {
  let latWellDraw = [d.latitude, d.longitude];
  if (inside(latWellDraw, coordsDraw[0])) {
    value.push(d);
  }
});

const divWellName = d3
  .select('#map')
  .data(value)
  .append('p')
  .attr('id', 'wellTableName')
  .style('opacity', '1');
```

What's inside the `value` variable:

[image]

with .datum the value from my const is:
[image]

Comment: Try `.datum(value)` or `.data([value])`, .data() expects an array containing items that represent different elements. You only have one element, so you want a one item array (`[value]`) or you can use `.datum()`, assuming I understand your end goal correctly.

Comment: @AndrewReid thanks for your answer! I'm try .datum(value) and the other way but noting works, is not showing any value yet :/

Comment: @AndrewReid i add a pic with .datum, can you see? please

Comment: @AndrewReid using .data([value]) its showing but just [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: The way your are setting up your selection for a data join is not correct. It should be: `const divWellName = d3.select('#map').selectAll(null).data(value).enter().append('p')`.

Comment: @altocumulus nothing happns

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on what you want. If you want to bind an array, you need to use the selectAll.
Check the example

```js
const values = [{name:"name A"}, {name:"name B"}];

const divWellName = d3
  .select('#map')
  .selectAll('p')
  .data(values)
  .enter().append('p')
  .attr('id', 'wellTableName')
  .style('opacity', '1')
  .html(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```